# Firebase google authentication need to double-click to log in

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, react-hooks

I try to login into firebase with google authentication (using React hooks), and I need to click on the button twice. I want the user to get into the homepage after the first click. What is wrong here?

googleLogin.js

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import { auth,app } from "../../../../config/firebase";

export const googleLogin = async (e, information, setInformation, signup, login, history) => {
  var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

  firebase
    .auth()
    .signInWithPopup(provider)
    .then( resp => {
      let {user, credential,additionalUserInfo: userInfo} = resp;
      let token = credential.accessToken;
      if (userInfo.isNewUser) signupWithGoogle(user, credential, userInfo);

    })
    .then(()=>{
      history.push('/')
    })
    .catch((error) => {
     ...
    });
};

const signupWithGoogle = (user, credential, userInfo)=>{
  app.firestore().collection('users').doc(user.uid).set({
    firstName: userInfo.profile.given_name,
    lastName: userInfo.profile.family_name});
    const batch = app.firestore().batch();
    const initData = [
      { Applied: { positionIds: [], title: 'Applied' } },
      { Contract: { positionIds: [], title: 'Contract' } },
      { Denied: { positionIds: [], title: 'Denied' } },
      { InProgress: { positionIds: [], title: 'In Progress' } },
      { ReceivedTask: { positionIds: [], title: 'Received Task' } },
    ];
    initData.forEach((doc) => {
      const docRef = app
        .firestore()
        .collection('users')
        .doc( user.uid)
        .collection('columns')
        .doc(Object.keys(doc)[0]);
      batch.set(docRef, Object.values(doc)[0]);
    });
    return batch.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem to login and the problem was in my HTLM code.
I was using a form.
To resolve it, I used a simpler code in HTLM.